# Please reopen question about physical travel affecting wifi connectivity

Tags: support, reopen-request

A new user posted a question about [speed of travel affecting wifi](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/58396), which was closed as Too Broad.

It seems a perfectly reasonable network theory question with pretty straightforward answers about doppler, getting out of wifi range, and current AP acquisition, which I gave in my answer.  All of those are specific, falsifiable, and not book length -- hence I'd say not "too broad". At least three people upvoted.

Please can it be reopened?  Perhaps there are other good answers.

Thanks for considering it.

Comment: Changed the tags per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/369973) on [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). The difficulty is that there were so many close votes that I am reluctant to use the moderator privilege to simply reopen without a show of support from other users.

Answer (score 1):

The question is fundamentally one of physics. As asked -- and not particularly well asked -- the answer is "any non-zero speed", because if you're moving and the AP isn't, you will, *eventually*, move out of range. You answered the physics question -- you'd have to be moving pretty fast to be out of tuning tolerance. (and you aren't going to accelerate to that speed while associated.) The practical NE answer "*depends*"... what's the scanning rate of the client? Is it a static address, or do we have variability from DHCP? What's the sensitivity (i.e. range) of the AP and client? What's the terrain? How much traffic do you need to send/recv? It's not a simple "yes/no" question.

(This gets debated in racing circles every few months/years. Taking VIR as a case study (because I *have*), if you place your AP on the pit wall at the center of the front straight, your android/iDevice will be in range to associate and pass traffic for a few seconds before moving back out of range. If you place an antenna on the roof of the patriot building, you'll be in range for minutes - possibly continuous. 900MHz non-wifi equipment does away with the range and terrain problems.)

Comment: Thanks, very interesting.  Is that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_International_Raceway ?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't help that it's one of the fastest places on the track. (and I did it when there was a tree there.) Other neat, useless trivia... the timing transponder is magnetic induction, not RF. (we discovered that entirely by accident with our EV race car -- DC motor: not a problem, AC motor: jams the timing loop.)